# wkhtmltopdf - Elements do not keep original position

Tags: php, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate a .pdf file for print out of HTML code. My issue is that when I generate the pdf, the HTML elements are moved around and do not stay with their original position.

My code for generating the pdf is:

```
        $address = 'http://www.example.com/sendpdf/' . $card . '/';

        $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
        $snappy->setOption('lowquality', null);
        $snappy->setOption('dpi', 100);
        $snappy->setOption('disable-smart-shrinking', true);
        $snappy->setOption('page-width', 127);
        $snappy->setOption('page-height', 178);
        $snappy->setOption('margin-left', 0);
        $snappy->setOption('margin-top', 0);
        $snappy->setOption('margin-right', 0);
        $snappy->setOption('margin-bottom', 0);
        $snappy->setOption('stop-slow-scripts', null);
        $snappy->setOption('enable-javascript', true);

        $pdf_content = array( $card, $snappy->getOutput($address) );
```

I've also tried looking at the HTML version with both Firefox, Safari and Chrome. In all versions the elements seem to be correctly positioned. It seems to only be an issue in the PDF version.

Anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: That happens sometimes. All you can do is to make a pre-pdf version and shift the number down more, so it displays correctly when converted to pdf.

Comment: But as you can see, it's not all elements that are pushed down. For example the name "Ashlyn" is same distance from the background bubble on both versions. So it would be difficult to automatically detect which ones that position different.

Comment: Unfortunately this happens. You should recheck how your elements are positioned. Some elements like `top` and `position` might get displayed wrong. To create PDF, you should rewrite the layout with another css to match the pdf.

Comment: If you haven't swapped out your wkhtmltopdf binary to 0.12.1, I would recommend doing that, too. New qt, so CSS is a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tweaking and improving this application to get it pixel perfect to the HTML, I have found out multiple things that helps to solve this problem. I hope some of you can use it.

1. Use `white-space: nowrap;`. For some reason on the PDF I got linebreaks on texts that didnt have any linebreaks in the HTML. I did a lot of testing of this and I could not find a good pattern to recreate the issue, but it seemed to be that in the PDF, it thought that the div was less wide in the HTML, and then pushed the content down to a second row. So I solved this by using white-space: nowrap;
2. Obviously it is important that both the PDF and the HTML you want to make it from have the exact same CSS Styling. But make sure that other things such as `<meta name="viewport">` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$snappy->setOption('viewport-size', 'WIDTHxHEIGHT')`,

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.